# for k, v in dict ///// TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, dictionary, iteration, keyvaluepair

```
import getpass

class LogInNow(object):

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.openfile = open(file, 'r')
        self.readfile = self.openfile.read()

    def authenticate(self):
        self.username = raw_input("Enter Username> ")
        self.password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password> ")
        for k, v in self.readfile():  <---------------------------------
            if k == self.username and v == self.password:
                print "It worked"
            else:
                print "Fail"""

go = LogInNow("password.txt")
go.authenticate()
```

This is a crude 'log-in' module that iterates through a dict located on password.txt and for now, exclusively displays messages based on match success.

The error is displayed in the title, and the erroneous line is the one with the arrow.

I have tried removing parentheses as well as all kinds of other stuff that I don't remember

Any ideas?

Comment: For starters, that line is indented incorrectly

Comment: If your file contains a dictionary, it's probably close enough to pass as JSON. so use the `json` module.

Comment: @shaktimaan Thats a miscopy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the other other issues (see below), you're setting `self.readfile` to a string, not a function. You're accidentally *calling* `self.openfile.read()` instead of grabbing the function itself. You wanted:

```
self.readfile = self.openfile.read  # <-- No parentheses at the end!
```

---

You've got a variety of other problems as well. For instance, the return value of the `read` method is a string, not a mapping or whatever sequence you're expecting, so the `for k, v in self.readfile()` won't work. You'll need to first parse the string into a dictionary, or sequence of tuples, or whatever you expect, somehow--how you do that depends on your requirements and the contents of the file, of course. As a side note, if you do want a dictionary (say, `mydict`) you should take the loop out in the first place and just check whether `mydict.get(self.username) == self.password`.

You've also got your looping line (the one you marked as the error) indented too little, though I suspect that's a copy/paste error.

Comment: I don't think that will work either. He's trying the return value of `read()` like it's a dict.

Comment: This is far from the only issue.

Comment: Yes, yes, I was editing in some comments on the other issues.

Comment: @HenryKeiter I do want a dict. What is the syntax to access the dict in that case? Can it be in .txt format or does it have to be .py?

Comment: @z82n You could load it as json I guess, but my guess is that it's faster to parse the file line by line and make a dictionary out of it. If you don't know how to do that, just search on SO, there are plenty of examples of reading a file into a dict.

Answer (score 2):

When you defined `readfile`, you already called the `read` function, so `readfile` is set to the return value of that function --- namely, a string containing the contents of the file.  You can't call that string.  Either change your loop to `for k, v in self.readfile` or change your earlier line to `self.readfile = self.openfile.read`.

However, your code still won't work, because you're trying to iterate over the entire file as if it were a serquence of key-value pairs.  But it's not; it's just one big string.  If you want to parse it into key-value pairs, you need to do that yourself somehow.

Comment: Ok, now how do I adjust the file to be a sequence of key-value pairs? Is it the type (.txt) that is wrong?

Comment: @z82n: No.  You need to take in the raw text of the file and parse it.  How to do that depends on what is in the file.  You could also think about using a standardized format like JSON.  Either way, this is really a separate question.